# Build a TXT file with text and variables and send variables via CURL using Bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, post

I am trying to build a .txt file with variable entries on multiple lines along with some static text and then send some of the variable data via CURL in a POST request.

ISSUES

At the moment, the .txt file is built but they are all added to a single line rather than multiple lines.

Only one variable (image1ID) is being sent via CURL, the other variable is being omitted from the payload.

IDEAL OUTCOME

TXT file to contain

```
file https://www.amazon.com/1.jpg
11
file https://www.amazon.com/2.jpg
13
...
```

and send all images variables via CURL

```
#!/bin/bash

image1Url=https://www.amazon.com/1.jpg
image1IDNumber=11
image2Url=https://www.amazon.com/2.jpg
image2IDNumber=13
image3Url=https://www.amazon.com/3.jpg
image3IDNumber=15
image4Url=https://www.amazon.com/4.jpg
image4IDNumber=17
image5Url=https://www.amazon.com/5.jpg
image5IDNumber=19

# Build txt using variables
echo "'file '${image1Url}\n${image1IDNumber}\n'file '${image2Url}\n${image2IDNumber}\n'file '${image3Url}\n${image3IDNumber}\n'file '${image4Url}\n${image4IDNumber}\n'file '${image5Url}\n${image5IDNumber}\n" >imagedetails.txt


curl -H "content-Type: application/json"  -d {"image1ID":"${image1IDNumber}","image2ID":"${image2IDNumber}"}  https://requestbin.herokuapp.com/18y57z13
```

Comment: I think you have two separate problems: creating a file `imagedetails.txt` in the correct format and passing data to `curl`. You should ask separate questions. Please show the actual and expected contents of your output file in your question **formatted as code blocks**. Regarding the `curl` problem: Please tell exactly how you detect the problem "Only one variable (image1ID) is being sent via CURL, the other variable is being omitted from the payload."

Comment: Hi @Bodo - Only one of the variables is passing to RequestBin, so I assume the JSON payload syntax is incorrect. The txt file will just be a tiny syntax change, hence why the issues are grouped together in the shell script in which I am having issues.

Comment: Please also show the actual output file. The quotes in your commands are strange. Add a line `set -x` to your script to see the commands that are actually executed. I suggest to use one pair of double quotes only before and after the complete argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i undestand what you're trying to do there. 
Im' wondern why you complicated things ? As it seems, your variables are 5, if they are dynamic you should've use a loop instead.

The following code gives your **Ideal Outcome** . The easiest way to do it :

```
#!/bin/bash

image1Url=https://www.amazon.com/1.jpg
image1IDNumber=11
image2Url=https://www.amazon.com/2.jpg
image2IDNumber=13
image3Url=https://www.amazon.com/3.jpg
image3IDNumber=15
image4Url=https://www.amazon.com/4.jpg
image4IDNumber=17
image5Url=https://www.amazon.com/5.jpg
image5IDNumber=19

# Build txt using variables

echo " file $image1Url " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " $image1IDNumber " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " file $image2Url " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " $image2IDNumber " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " file $image3Url " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " $image3IDNumber " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " file $image4Url " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " $image4IDNumber " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " file $image5Url " >> imagedetails.txt
echo " $image5IDNumber " >> imagedetails.txt

### Post the content of the file as follow :

a="\"image1ID\":\"${image1IDNumber}\",\"image2ID\":\"${image2IDNumber}\"" 
b="'$a'"
curl -H "content-Type: application/json"  -d $b https://requestbin.herokuapp.com/18y57z13
```

you should file an **imagedetails.txt** file containing the following output :

```
 file https://www.amazon.com/1.jpg
 11
 file https://www.amazon.com/2.jpg
 13
 file https://www.amazon.com/3.jpg
 15
 file https://www.amazon.com/4.jpg
 17
 file https://www.amazon.com/5.jpg
 19
```

Comment: This is looking good for the TXT file, thanks. Still getting the CURL error in passing the 2nd variable ```curl: (6) Could not resolve host: image2ID``` I just want to pass specific variables and not the txt contents.

Comment: I this the good thing is to use your variables outside the curl. Have a look at the solution, i edited it to suit your need.

Comment: That's almost it, however, it needs delivering in valid JSON format so it arrives like this ```{"image1ID":"11","image2ID":"13"}```

Comment: for the json to work, you need to wrap your json data between simple quotes

Comment: ```a={\"image1ID\":\"${image1IDNumber}\",\"image2ID\":\"${image2IDNumber}\"} ``` has done it, cheers.